# Combine two ELF binaries

Tags: binary-analysis, elf, binary, binary-editing

Without having access to the original source code, is there a way to combine two ELF binaries with the main() in the first binary pointing to the main() in the second binary ?

In other words, I mean adding memory section for the content inside the second main().

Comment: How is this different from simply running the second binary?

Comment: @IgorSkochinsky See https://www.docdroid.net/e3kiS0e/compact-control-flow-integerity-in-linu1-pdf

Comment: I don’t get how that link answers my question. To clarify, you said “first main pointing to the second” which to me  basically means “execute second main instead of first”. If you meant something else, try to reword your question.

Comment: For you have two executables with each a main method how should those main methods be executed? Sequentially after another or in parallel?

Comment: @Robert in what order do you want them executed?

Comment: @multithr3at3d This is not my question. I just pointed out the possibilities.

Comment: @Robert sequentially

Comment: Can you give a bit more context to the problem you are working on? It sounds like you are talking about binary patching (something you can do with Radare2 and other tools).

Comment: @peachykeen I do not have access to original source code for both ELF binaries. And I wish to combine the two ELF binaries into a single ELF binary with no functionality changes

Comment: @peachykeen The second binary (app) is quite complicated compared to the first binary (hello). See [this](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1XOWZ01JDhprwPFVmzffzFyH6LOQOcVJL/view?usp=sharing) which contains a simple binary and a complicated binary.

Please note that I will not have access to the original source code of the two ELF binaries.

Comment: @kevin can you please provide more information for why you want to merge the two binaries? What is your end goal? This will help us come up with a solution for you.

Comment: @kevin Also, if you can post examples of any code (if necessary) in the original question, that would be great. I don't want to download random executables from the internet.

Comment: @peachykeen try to use https://github.com/sangfansh/SGX101_sample_code/tree/master/HelloEnclave to compile the second ELF binary which is complicated. And you can just use a simple helloworld for the first ELF binary which is simple.

Comment: @peachykeen as for why need to merge the two binaries, it is to allow a normal source code like helloworld to use intel SGX feature when only a SGX binary (no source code) is presented to us.

Comment: @Robert What is the purpose of this [_init(EVP_PKEY_CTX * ctx) function](https://gist.github.com/promach/14cfef71cf3a1630507553da67105c10#file-app-L364) ?

Comment: @kevin: Sorry I don't know. `libc_csu_init` is the program constructor and `EVP_PKEY_CTX` is a "public key algorithm context" from OpenSSL. IMHO the both parts don't match together. May be the parameter type was guessed wrong?

Comment: @Robert but it seems like all other ELF binaries also have the same _init() function

Comment: @kevin yes `libc_csu_init` is a standard method, that is why I am confused that it should take an OpenSSL parameter. I don't think the disassembly is correct regarding the parameter type.